# regex to validate router parameter not working

Tags: regex, laravel, routes

I want to validate if an email is being send correctly in `routes`, however it isn't working when I put a `regex` condition (like explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints))

Basically, I added:

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Auth',
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    // ...
    Route::get('checkemail/{email}', 'AuthController@check_email')->where('email', '@.*?\.');
});
```

even if I pass a valid email I get an `404 not found`. what can I do to make the code works well?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `.+` before `@` in your regex.

Edit: I forgot to mention, you can put the same thing after `@`, and the current regex seems like it's wrong as well. I won't go into it, but validating email should not be complicated for a lot of reasons.

Comment: first, welcome! I added ```.+```, however if I pass a non-valid e-mail I get 200 ok as response

Comment: I mentioned that  in my edit, you don't really need to do that. The only certain way is to do confirmation emails. Even validating a domain isn't enough.

Comment: actually what was requested to me is to just validate if the string passed has just one @ and a dot, later it'll have an domain validation

Comment: Why a string and a dot, though? You'd need another `.+` after that, since most emails wouldn't pass. It's basically validating `foo@bar.`. And thanks for the welcome!

Comment: it still doesnt working. I actually got the simplest regex to see if it works, however or it pass for a valid and invalid string, or it doesnt pass for both :/

Comment: Could you probably give me a list of valid strings? Maybe then I could help - if it's a regex issue. There's also https://regex101.com/ and you can test PHP regexes.
If you don't do email confirmation, there's really no point in validating anything more than `@` and alphanumeric symbols. You could also check the length; the max for email addresses is 254 characters.